# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Getting permission denied even with admin initialized

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I setup my cloud functions with `firebase-admin` like :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fn = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(fn.config().firebase);
```

However I am getting permission denied upon writing on the database. What's weird is it only happens to some collection but not to all of them. Some works, some won't.

My understanding of `admin.initializeApp(fn.config().firebase);` is that this will allow my cloud functions to have an absolute power over the database regardless of the `security rules`.

Here's the error:

[image]

**EDIT**

I write the data like this.

```
exports.foo = fn.database.ref('some-path').onWrite(e => {
    // some handling
    const ref = e.data.ref;

    return ref.child('bar').set('some-data').then( // ).catch( // );
})
```

Comment: Well this is awkward. It appears to be working now. WTH happened?

Comment: Are you performing your writes using [admin.database()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database)?

Comment: At @BobSnyder No, should I? Please kindly check the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain full access to the database from the [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) provided in an event, use [adminRef](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#adminRef):

> Returns a Reference to the Database location where the triggering
>   write occurred. Similar to ref, but with full read and write access
>   instead of end-user access

```
exports.foo = fn.database.ref('some-path').onWrite(e => {
    // some handling
    const ref = e.data.adminRef;  // <== CHANGED

    return ref.child('bar').set('some-data').then( // ).catch( // );
})
```

Comment: Whoah!? There's `.adminRef` ?? OMG. Let me try it.

Comment: All right! It worked. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot Bob.